# Edit message as new in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

Is there a way to edit messages as new in Gmail?

I wish for something similar to forward function but with the message body unaltered. Or for a better explanation to use existing emails as a template.

---

#### [**Update**] Why forward doesn't work for me :

Click on forward on a message, delete the signature and FW from the message title :

Message looks OK on the editing form, send it.

[image]

Check the message on the other end and here is how it looks :

[image]

## note the small button `...` in the body, that is the message received!

click on the `...` button, the text is colored indigoish :

[image]

**What I want** is for the the message in the recipient side to look like this :

[image]

---

Currently I'm holding some templates on gist as raw text and copy them manually and it annoys me to format and embed the images each time I send the message.

Copy/paste from sent messages works at some extent with the text but the images are not embedded and sometimes the format is corrupted.

Comment: If you forward, you only need to delete your signature and the quoted headers. The message is otherwise as sent by the first author. (At least in my experience.) Are you talking about something else? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: No, it is not unclear ... I tried a better explanation.

Comment: Ah. The forwarded text gets a color added to it. No, I'm afraid there's not a setting you can change in Gmail to do what you want. You'll need to use a third-party client.

Comment: The color is the smallest problem, the `...` button is the big one. is small and  people would think there is an empty message

Answer (score 2):

1. In Gmail, enable IMAP in Settings » Forwarding and POP/IMAP.
2. Install [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/), and configure the Gmail account using IMAP.
3. In Thunderbird, right-click on email to forward, and choose Edit as New Message.
4. Address the message, and Send.
5. Repeat steps 3-4.

Comment: And on an Android phone?

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding should work for this. But you have to change the subject (click the downward arrow and then `Edit Subject`). If the subject has Fw or hint text like that, then gmail will interpret it as a forward. Give that a shot and see if it solves your formatting issues and let me know!

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect a proper E-Mail app via IMAP (I'm using Evolution on Ubuntu 20.04).
2. Click "Edit as New Message"
3. **Save the new message as draft in the "Drafts" folder.** It will be synchronized via IMAP to your G-Mail account.
4. Go to G-Mail and open the new message from the "Drafts" folder.

Comment: I m afraid no such imap app exists on Android phones. At least with the desired functionality.