# Forward from Gmail without the additional "fw:" notes

Tags: gmail

I'm applying for jobs. I've got to send the same cover letter to multiple addresses, albeit making some minor edits. But every time I choose to forward an email, I see that the subject line adds "Fwd:" as a prefix, and in the email body, it adds the details of senders and recipients of the original message under the heading "---------- Forwarded message ----------".

Editing it out manually, or even copypasting into a new email, are what I've been doing. Is there any simpler way? Maybe an option in the settings that I missed?

I want to get the original email content, attachments, and subject line without any changes when I choose to forward to another address. How can I do that?

Comment: What is wrong with editing that out?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise Editing it out manually is what I've been doing. Is there any other way? Maybe an option in the settings that I missed?

Comment: Shame they don't have an "Edit as New" option

Comment: You could probably write a script to do that, but Gmail has no native way to do it.

Comment: Related: [Edit message as new in Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/85348/354).

Answer (score 1):

Try a Mail Merge for Gmail technique like the [Mail Merge with Attachments Add-on](https://www.labnol.org/software/mail-merge-with-gmail/13289/)